# Cannot launch a simple .Net app - it creates 3 copies of itself in Task Manager and nothing happens

Tags: c#, launch

We have recently released a game called "Zombie Hunter, Inc." to Steam http://store.steampowered.com/app/387130.

We got reports from different parts of the world (one from Russia, one from Ukraine, one from the US) that the game simpley won't launch at all, while adding three (or even more) copies of itself into Task Manager, which cannot be canceled other than by restarting the PC. I've contacted one of the users who had this issue and gave him a simple app, targeting .Net 4.0 (not Client profile) with the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


namespace Main
{
    public class MainN
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("launched ok!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

It references Microsoft.CSharp and System nothing else AND IT WON'T LAUNCH!

In fact what happens is the mouse shows loading icon and THREE instances of the app are added to the Task Manager and then nothing - just nothing at all. You cannot remove the instances from the Task Manager - you only need to restart the PC. Moreover, the user told me that he had a similar issue with other games recently. And that after some time the issue just goes away and they start working as normal

Here is the Visual Studio project I used to build a release version of this app:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8dysKzeYPBQcm1nd0M0dnZYV28/view?usp=sharing

Did anyone have a similar issue? Is there a way to prevent it?

User specs:

Operating System: Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit

Processor: AMD FX(tm)-8320 Eight-Core Processor 3.5GHz

Memory: 8192MB RAM

DirectX Version: DirectX 11

Card name: AMD Radeon R9 200 Series (Dedicated Memory: 3072 MB)
Native Mode: 1920 x 1080(p) (60.000Hz)

Comment: What's about antivirus on the machines with the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ok the user turned off his Avast anti-virus and it launched. You gotta learn your whole life right? :)

Comment: But it's still unclear. Maybe thay should run full scan by AV. Or try to reproduce the problem and contact Avast support.